# TemplateRef items being destroyed every time their collection changes

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem creating a component that renders a a collection of items based on a custom `Observable` and custom item `TemplateRef`.

The component takes the `Observable` and `TemplateRef` as inputs and renders them appropriately. The problem comes in where the collection changes and all items in the collection are destroyed and recreated.

This is obviously problematic where I depend on animations to indicate items entering and leaving the collection (or changing position in the collection).

If my component, instead, renders the component directly (i.e. not the `TemplateRef` input) I don't have this issue of components being destroyed every time the collection changes. I think I may have narrowed the problem down to passing the `item` from the `*ngFor` on the templates outlet context.

I've got a reproduction of the problem [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QlSxk924r5CVxG6IskXt?p=preview) demonstrating the difference between rendering the `TemplateRef` and component directly. The `ngOnDestroy` is logged to the console as well as an animation for when the component `:enter`s. I think this plnkr demonstrates the problem clearly.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I may have narrowed the problem down to passing the item from
>   the *ngFor on the templates outlet context.

Yeah, that's because `context` parameter always gets new object reference:

```html
context: { index: index, item: item }
```

and therefore `ngOnChange` hook will be called inside `ngTemplateOutletDirective`:

[image]

as you can see in the picture above template will be removed.

To avoid it i would suggest you using built-in `@Input() ngForTemplate` property on `ngFor`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; template: itemTemplate, trackBy: itemTrack"></div>
```

and for your `#feedItem` custom template change `let-item` variable from:

```html
<ng-template #feedItem let-item="item">
```

to:

```html
<ng-template #feedItem let-item="$implicit">
```

or simply:

```html
<ng-template #feedItem let-item>
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oKc6anAALNrrDzeDuQVi?p=preview)**

See also

- [ngTemplateOutlet prevents directive from working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592646/ngtemplateoutlet-prevents-directive-from-working-correctly)

Comment: This is great, thanks. But what if I want to pass more data, not just the `item`. For example, the item `index` or another property from the component.

Comment: `index` is already available https://plnkr.co/edit/I00K8fSCpM45y8Fvg0QV?p=preview For other property just prepare `items` array in `ngOnInit`

Comment: So to pass properties other than things like `first`, `last`, `index` etc, I would need to add those properties directly to each `item` in the array?

Comment: No these things are available https://plnkr.co/edit/OZ6PJvKpTkGH7INpnt0I?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. If for example I wanted to pass the `interval` property (which may be dynamic) to the item component, would I need to add an `interval` property to each `item` in `ngOnInit` of the `MyItemListComponent` now that I'm no longer explicitly passing a `context`?

Comment: Seems yes, if you want to have new property then you have to add it to each of item because template takes `item` as `$implicit` parameter