# ngTemplateOutlet prevents directive from working correctly

Tags: angular

I am building a tabs component and in its headers i added a ripple component that attaches a class and does the animation as seen in code below.

However even though it works in all my other components i.e buttons seems that it fails to work when used inside an ngTemplateOutlet context. Perhaps i am doing something wrong. Any tips welcome.

tabsComponentTemplate

```
<div class="nui-tab-group">
  <ng-template #defaultTabsHeader let-tabs="tabs">
    <ul class="nui-tab-group-buttons" *ngIf="tabs">
      <li class="tab-button"
          [ngClass]="{selected: tab.selected}"
          (click)="selectedTab(tab)"
          ripple-c
          *ngFor="let tab of tabs">{{ tab.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="headerTemplate || defaultTabsHeader; context: tabsContext"></ng-container>

  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

ripple component main part

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event', '$event.currentTarget'])
  click(event, element) {
    if (this.rippleStyle === 'expand') {
      let ripple = document.createElement('span'),
        rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
        radius = Math.max(rect.height, rect.width),
        left = event.pageX - rect.left - radius / 2 - document.body.scrollLeft,
        top = event.pageY - rect.top - radius / 2 - document.body.scrollTop;

      ripple.className = 'expand-ripple-effect animate';
      ripple.style.width = ripple.style.height = radius + 'px';
      ripple.style.left = left + 'px';
      ripple.style.top = top + 'px';
      ripple.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        element.removeChild(ripple);
      });
      element.appendChild(ripple);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you create plunker?

Comment: @yurzui i am trying to create one but a lot of things do not work like the css for some reason. Do you have any angular 4 sample plunkers i can use of? the ones i found suck

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uaxqwg?file=app%2Fripple.directive.ts

Comment: @yurzui just got mine to work thank you though! here `https://plnkr.co/edit/aYET8s` .  Notice how clicking the button the ripple works but doesn't work on the tabs header

Comment: Seems you didn't save your plunker

Comment: @yurzui sorry yeah noticed, used your link - think this is working now? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqv2kk

Comment: Thanks, now i can reproduce it. Will investigate

Comment: awesome i greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I know what is the problem

Comment: that was fast, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for this is that your list is rerendered every time change detection happens because you're passing new object to `context` every time:

```typescript
get tabsContext() {
  return {
    tabs: this.tabs
  }
}
```

NgTemplateOutlet directive sees this changes and clears templateю

Use prepared data for template

```typescript
tabsContext: any;

ngAfterContentInit (): void {  
  ...  
  this.tabsContext = {
    tabs: this.tabs
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkcemu?file=app/tabs.component.ts)**

See also similar case

- [TemplateRef items being destroyed every time their collection changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238498/templateref-items-being-destroyed-every-time-their-collection-changes)